# Nginx reverse proxy + Angular served by Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an angular app, `my-app`, which I build locally with `ng build --prod` and serve with Nginx dockerized, the `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY /dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

As long as I launch a container based on an image build with this `Dockerfile`, it works.
Though, I need to put another Nginx acting as a reverse proxy before this one, I want to redirect the traffic with a route like `/my-app` to the internal Nginx serving Angular, like so:

```
http://DOMAIN/my-app ---> Reverse Proxy ---> Nginx+Angular
```

I'll use Docker Compose for local dev. My `docker-compose.yml` is very simple:

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        container_name: my-nginx
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    my-app:
        container_name: my-app
        build: ./my-app
```

For the Angular app, I redefine `"baseHref": "./my-app/"` in my `angular.json` file, I build again and I configure the reverse proxy as follows:

```
events {}

http {

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root                /var/www;
    index               index.html;

    location / {
        index           index.html;
    }

    location /my-app {
      rewrite                     /my-app/(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass                  http://my-app:80;
      proxy_set_header Host       $host;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
      proxy_set_header Host       $host;
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the `index.html` in the `location /` directive is a custom one, not the Angular app's one. Thus, I expect my reverse proxy to serve the `index.html` when visiting the route `/`, which it does, but I get a **400 Bad Request** error when I try to visit `/my-app/`. 
Does someone have a solution for this? What am I getting wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing. I would do it that way.

```
    # Maybe not necessary to redirect from /my-app to /my-app/.
    location ~ ^/my-app$ {
      set $myargs $args;  # workaround to encode spaces in query string!
      return 303 $scheme://$server_name/my-app/$is_args$myargs;
    }

    location /my-app/ {  # works mostly with and sometimes without slash at end!
      proxy_pass                  http://my-app:80/;  # slash at end is goddamn important here; it hides /my-app/ and does all the $request_uri or regex, $is_args and $args magic for you!
      proxy_set_header Host       $host;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
      proxy_set_header Host       $host;
    }
```

If your back end sends redirects you are maybe screwed. Check with `curl -IL http://my-app`. If you see 301, 302, 303 up to 308 with a target `Location:` - it's a redirect. But maybe my other answer there can help (rewrite redirects): https://serverfault.com/a/986034/304842 or try `proxy_redirect`. The problem that I seeing is that you want websockets!? Maybe you need `sub_filter` or `subs_filter` too, to remove `/my-app/` from source code for other links and resources. Check with [F12] -> Network in your browser.

Comment: If I send `curl -IL http://localhost:8081`, I get:
```$ curl -IL http://localhost:8081
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   808    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

Comment: Still not working, now the URL http://localhost/my-app/ returns "400 Bad Request
nginx/1.19.2".

Comment: Dunno, can you update question with your current config? Also `/var/log/nginx/error.log` could be interesting.

Comment: goddamn slash in proxy_pass take me 15 hours, until I read this answer